# When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Inside of a PHP file register.php I have the following alert text:

```
echo '<div id="id01" class="box">' . '<div class="example">' . '<span class="close">&times;</span>' .'<h3>Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been sent to your address. Please click on the link in that email in order to activate your account.</h3>'.'</div>'.'</div>';
```

also I have the following CSS code:

```
<style>
    .box {       
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    padding-top: 60px;
}        
    .example {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; 
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 60%; 
    padding: 50px;
}
```

and the alert text works fine so far.

The issue when I try to close de box with the followin code:

```
<script>
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

does not work !
does not close the text box when I click on  (x), how can i run this code in PHP file ?

note: this was the based on this w3shools modal code:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

Comment: where span and modal are defined in the JS code ?

Comment: Hi Temani, I think so is in the span.onclick = function()...

Comment: also, in the js how do you defined `span`? you must get error in the console

Comment: Hi Samvel,  no console error. The span is defined in the echo '...'; The issue is only does not close the text box when I click on (x).  Now I'm trying also to define the js into the echo '...'; also. Thanks

Comment: `span.onclick = function() {` I mean this `span`. where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code.

PHP：

```
echo '<div id="id01" class="box" onclick= "closeBox()"> ....</div>';
```

JS:

```
function closeBox(){
           document.getElementById(“id01”).style.display=“none”;
}
```

Comment: Hi lazytortoise, I put the function closeBox()code in the Js but did not work. What do you think if I put it inside PHP echo ' ....'; But I do not know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should instead of removing it from outside. do it inline

```
echo '<div id="id01" class="box" onclick="$(this).remove();">' . '<div class="example">' . '<span class="close">&times;</span>'
```

or

```
echo '<div id="id01" class="box">' . '<div class="example">' . '<span class="close" onclick="$("#id01").remove();">&times;</span>'
```

Comment: Hi Mooga, I tried but I have the following error "
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input " but I keep trying.

Comment: Hi Mooga, I'm trying to put this code inline:{       '<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>'   }Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Just put it in the HTML which you gave in echo

Comment: But with double quotes not single